# How to connect a Pipeline build agent to private Artifacts registry?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-extensions

We have packages being published to our private Artifacts repository that are dependencies in other Pipeline builds.

When we add our private Artifacts registry `https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Artifacts@Local/npm/registry/` the build agent does not seem to have access and shows 401 errors.

How can we authorize the Pipeline build agent so that it can access our private Artifacts repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you're using either the [npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=vsts) or [npm Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=vsts) task (which will generate an .npmrc that has the build's access token) and that you've given the [appropriate identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines) access to your feed.

Comment: Using the `Npm` task worked! It looks like one of the example YAML files was using a raw `script` command which should probably be changed: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-javascript/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: Also you may need to check the "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token
" under "Additional Settings" of the "Agent Job" options.